# Allow Twitter to load iframe to about: or resource://

Tags: firefox-addon

My addon is meant for Twitter. I inject an `iframe` and then set its path to a page in my addon. I have tried `chrome://` with `contentaccessible=true` in my `chrome.manifest`. I tried creating an about page with `URI_SAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CONTENT`. I tried then to creeate a resource uri that points to the about page. I then tried resource uri pointing to the chrome:// page. All of them give me:

```
 Security Error: Content at https://twitter.com/ may not load or link to resource://tweetereditor/.
```

Wherever of course the `resource://tweetereditor/` is the URL i tried to access. Is there a way to get around this without using a webprogress listener to add to each twitter request the:

```
 headers.push({name: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Allowing page/content scope access to browser scope can lead to security issues anyway.

How complicated is the content of the iframe?

The more secure method is to generate the content and insert it into the iframe programmatically (ie `appendChild()` etc)

Comment: It's a full fledged rich text editor. If I inject it into the document I am having to fight with twitter jquery styling and overtaking my stuff, and then twitters css messing up my stuff :( Right now I am overlaying a `xul:browser` and then loading it but it is bad because I can't support mobile :( I released addon with this xul trick - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeter/ - Doesn't webetensions allow cross site behavior with `content_security_policy` in manifest.json?